# How to check that I work with instance of subclass?

Tags: java, oop, solid-principles, instanceof

I read an interesting article on the third SOLID principle: https://stackify.com/solid-design-liskov-substitution-principle/

At the same time, I read that using an `instanceof` operator can be a violation of the SOLID rule. How to deal with the following problem.

I have two classes (pseudo code):

```
CoffeeMachine {
    brewCoffee();
}

PremiumCoffeeMachine extends CoffeeMachine {
    brewCoffee()
    brewEspresso()
}
```

Then somewhere in the program I got a collection of coffee machines

`Set<CoffeeMachine> coffeeMachines`

Now I'd like to make coffee with each of the coffee machines. How will I know I can make an espresso without using an `instanceof` operator?

Maybe it's the only way, but I read many times today that an `instanceof` operator breaks the SOLID

Do you know an interesting article or can you provide a solution to such a problem? Maybe I I wrong and SOLID says that subclasses should't contains extra methods?

Comment: instanceof doesn't break SOLID. The idea that is being expressed on the link that you provided is that the contract for brewCoffee SHOULD NOT be stricter in the subclass, as this breaks the contract. And actually Java won't let you do this

Comment: Why do you want to know that it is an espresso? `CoffeeMakeI` can `brewCoffee()`. If you want an espresso, just swap your `CoffeeMachine` with a `PremiumCoffeMachine`, which should override `brewCoffee` (and not `brewEspresso`).

Comment: PremiumCoffeeMachine has 2 function. It can brew simple coffee and also espresso, maybe other types. I would like to know if I can do it, because I prefer espresso.

Answer (score 3):

Your given reference gives a lot of insight on how you could deal with this problem.

In the end, you want to iterate over a `Collection` of `CoffeeMachine` instances and instruct them to brew coffee, as described by `brewCoffee()`. And you are correct, to know if your machine is a premium one, you would have to use the `instanceof` operator.

If you want a more flexible solution, you could use the following design:

```
public interface CoffeeMachine {

    // check if this machine supports a given selection
    // if not, #brewCoffee should throw an exception
    boolean supports(CoffeeSelection selection);
   
    CoffeeDrink brewCoffee(CoffeeSelection selection);
}
```

Now, one could imagine a `PremiumCoffeeMachine` that supports an `EspressoCoffee` (a special `CoffeeSelection`). `CoffeeSelection` ifself can be an `interface`, a `class` or an `enum`, depending on the complexity and requirements of the different coffees.

Comment: I like the example. Really straight forward

Comment: Thank you for this example. I also think that method could be good solution. 

As I understand it is not wrong to use instanceof if it is not he way to change logic which is designed in super class. When I use instanceof to check if it is possible to invoke extra functions, it is ok? Of course you solution with interfaces is also nice. Does it have better performance?

Answer (score 1):

instanceof doesn't break SOLID. The idea that is being expressed on the link that you provided is that the contract for brewCoffee SHOULD NOT be stricter in the subclass, as this breaks the contract. And actually Java won't let you do this

Comment: Please provide a link or more information on why a explicit dispatch based on subclass does not violated LSP